# How do I get the current value of a given variable name when writing a Roslyn Analyser?

Tags: c#, roslyn, code-analysis, roslyn-code-analysis

The following code snippet is the code I wish to analyse:

```
var name = "Michael";
name = "John";
var person = new Person(name);
```

And let's say my analyser should complain if the length of `name` given to the `constructor` of `Person` is less than 5.

I know how to get the value of a string literal `var person = new Person("John")` that is passed in to this object creation expression, check the first arguments type and then if it's a string literal grab it's `Value` property.

But how do I get the analyser to give me the value of `name` at the `Person` object creation expression site. This `name` is clearly well defined in the code, so should be possible in this case.

Thus far I've tried something along the lines of...

```
var nameExpr = (IdentifierNameSyntax)objectCreation.ArgumentList?.Arguments.First()?.Expression;
var nameDataFlow = context.SemanticModel.AnalyzeDataFlow(nameExpr);
```

It looks like I can figure out by using this data flow the value of `name`, but it would seem to involve a very complex and flaky set of code, and would appear to me to only work if the declarations were inside the data flow code block. I'd like it to be able to resolve this token to it's actual value (if possible) even across the global compilation.

Even if I wrote global compilation hooks myself, I'd have to manually track every assignment to the variable (including from other variables and method calls etc.)

Is there an easy way to ask the library to do this for me, and just give me the variable's value at the call site if it can?

Comment: An analyzer operates at compile-time. You cannot build a compile-time tool that will always know what the run-time values of your variable are. Imagine that you assign `name` a value from userinput (eg. from `Console.ReadLine()`)

Comment: Aye I've done some more research on this, it seems roslyn doesn't have an algorithm for this at the moment. But it can be implemented, if it resolves to an expression finally (rather than a value) then I can do some analysis based on that, even in multi-threaded environments, I can report on the possible values of it, and if the analysis reaches a certain complexity then I could finally bail on it and say "I don't know" what this variable's value is or could be.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an easy way to ask the library to do this for me, and just give me the variable's value at the call site if it can?

No, in fact this is provably [impossible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) for an arbitrary program with arbitrary inputs.

One exception is when the variable is a compile-type constant (`const`), in which case you can get its value using [`SemanticModel.GetConstantValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.semanticmodel.getconstantvalue?view=roslyn-dotnet#Microsoft_CodeAnalysis_SemanticModel_GetConstantValue_Microsoft_CodeAnalysis_SyntaxNode_System_Threading_CancellationToken_).

> I can report on the possible values of it, and if the analysis reaches a certain complexity then I could finally bail on it and say "I don't know" what this variable's value is or could be.

This would be complex for even simple cases. Think about all of the ways that the value could change:

- The variable could be conditionally assigned to within the code block. How are you going to try to determine whether the condition is true?
- The variable could be captured in a lambda function. How are you going to analyze the lambda function and its invocations?
- The variable could be assigned to an expression, which could include calls to other methods, etc. How are you going to determine the value of an arbitrary expression?
- The value of the variable could depend on data read by your program at runtime. For a simple example, what is the value of `DateTime.Now`? You can't determine this using static analysis.
- Many others.

Comment: You are right that this going to get completely out of hand very quickly, 2^n potential values where n is the conditional assignment count just to start with! I think I'll start with the case where the variable is declared within the block, and cover literal assignments only (as is the case in my specific example), then it will be interesting to see how much further you can go with current resources.

Comment: I had more or less this same question (for an incremental generator), and hadn't yet reached this (correct) conclusion. I am currently accepting arguments that are either `null` literals or object creation expressions (e.g., `new(...)`). I am using the `IArgumentOperation` API, so it occurs to me that I may be able to additionally provide provisional support for `IFieldReferenceOperation` if the field is `readonly` and initialized inline with the same kind of expressions that I'm already looking for. Properties and local variables are probably similarly too complex to validate and immutable.

Comment: A brief addition to my previous comment - `static readonly` fields can be initialized but then still overwritten inside of a `static` constructor. Once you're inside the `static` constructor then you're back to square one and all bets are off on what the final value will be. The option to use a `static readonly` field might still warrant allowing them versus only supporting inline argument expressions, but it would require a big, **bold** disclaimer that only the inline initialization will be recognized by the source generator (in my use case, YMMV).