# GetOperation returning null for VariableDeclaratorSyntax, VariableDeclarationSyntax, and FieldDeclarationSyntax

Tags: c#, roslyn, sourcegenerators, csharp-source-generator, incremental-generator

In a C# [incremental generator](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/incremental-generators.md) I am authoring, beginning from an `ArgumentSyntax`, I am trying to inspect the inline initializer for a `readonly` field referenced as a method argument. Understanding that [value inspection is impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51563659/1136311), I thought that I could traverse the syntax tree to find the definition of the field, and if it had an inline initializer, then I could at least use that value (with the understanding that the field could be overwritten in a constructor).

```
var argumentOperation = (IArgumentOperation)context.SemanticModel.GetOperation(argumentSyntax, cancellationToken)!;
switch (argumentOperation.Parameter?.Name)
{
    case "argumentToInspect":
        break;
    default:
        return;
}
if (argumentOperation.Value is not IFieldReferenceOperation fieldReferenceOperation ||
    !fieldReferenceOperation.Field.IsReadOnly)
{
    return;
}
var fieldSyntaxNode = fieldReferenceOperation.Field.DeclaringSyntaxReferences[0].GetSyntax(cancellationToken);
Debug.WriteLine($"fieldSyntaxNode kind: {fieldSyntaxNode.Kind()}"); // VariableDeclarator
Debug.WriteLine($"parent kind: {fieldSyntaxNode.Parent.Kind()}"); // VariableDeclaration
Debug.WriteLine($"grandparent kind: {fieldSyntaxNode.Parent.Parent.Kind()}"); // FieldDeclaration

var nodeOperation = context.SemanticModel.GetOperation(fieldSyntaxNode, cancellationToken); // null
var parentOperation = context.SemanticModel.GetOperation(fieldSyntaxNode.Parent, cancellationToken); // null
var grandparentOperation = context.SemanticModel.GetOperation(fieldSyntaxNode.Parent.Parent, cancellationToken); // null
```

The field in question is declared such as:

```
private static readonly MyClass instance = new();
```

Which is then referenced as:

```
MyMethod(instance);
```

Given that I am able to find the `FieldDeclarationSyntax` (`fieldSyntaxNode.Parent.Parent`), I'm not sure why I'm unable to find any relevant `IOperation`s (e.g., `IVariableDeclaratorOperation`, `IVariableDeclarationOperation`, or `IFieldInitializerOperation`). The field declaration and field reference passed as an argument (to `MyMethod`) are in the same file, so my understanding is that the same semantic model (`context.SemanticModel`) should be able to produce the relevant operations, but I am only getting `null` from `GetOperation` on the field declaration.

Am I approaching this the wrong way? Given that I can find the syntax of the field declaration, I could try to manually parse the text for the information that I need, but I don't understand why I can't use the `IOperation` API to inspect the field initializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am still unclear as to which nodes might generate either `IVariableDeclaratorOperation` or `IVariableDeclarationOperation`, I *was* able to discover the `IFieldInitializerOperation` (which is ultimately the one I was actually looking for).

In the case of an *inline field initializer*, `GetOperation` will yield the `IFieldInitializerOperation` for the `EqualsValueClauseSyntax` node, which is a descendant node of the `FieldDeclarationSyntax`.

Tangentially related to what I originally asked, I can discover an initializing assignment *in the constructor* by finding an `AssignmentExpressionSyntax` with `Kind` of `SimpleAssignmentExpression` which has a `ConstructorDeclarationSyntax` ancestor node. From this node I can receive an `ISimpleAssignmentOperation` with a `Target` of `IFieldReferenceOperation`.

Given the `Value` of the `IFieldInitializationOperation` and/or `ISimpleAssignmentOperation`, I am able to use this information to more powerfully (and correctly) parse the initialization of `readonly` fields.